# Apache POI get data from another sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I'm trying to populate dropdowns with data validation on apache poi.

```
Name namedRange = workbook.createName();
namedRange.setNameName("myList");
namedRange.setRefersToFormula("'lookupSheet'!$B$4:$B$(LOOKUP(2;1/(B:B<>\"\");ROW(B:B))");
XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint)
      dvHelper.createFormulaListConstraint("myList");
```

And this is the exception i'm facing:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Parse error near char 17 '$' in specified formula ''lookupSheet'!$A$4:$A$(LOOKUP(2;1/(B:B<>"");ROW(B:B))'. Expected number, string, or defined name
```

I know the error is pretty clear, but i can't see what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry haven't tried it out, but is this static reference "$" in front of "$(LOOKUP...)" really working? I probably would work with indirect()

Comment: That lookup is just returning a number (of last non empty cell on a column). basically it should be `("'lookupSheet'!$B$4:$B$12");` for example